# How to Display Grid view with image and text

Tags: android

How to display My grid View Like Below Screen short

[I want to display like this  ,Click here for screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJttl.png)

Comment: Search in Google and you will find tons of tutorial and sample code. You will only get down vote here for this question.

Comment: can You please provide any link to me

Comment: [Gridview with image and text](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gridview%20with%20image%20and%20text%20in%20android)

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this tutorial](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html) which might help you to understand the basics of using `GridView`.You can customize it like you need.